# Save reports according to choice from a sub form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a main form called (`frmcarSearch`) that displays table data called (`tblCar`).

The form contains three drop-down menu (`cmbCar`, `cmbType`, `cmbGroup`) that allow user to filter data and display them in a sub-form called (`frmCarSub`)
and there are three buttons to save the filtered data `btnPrint`, `btnPDF`, `btnExcel`.

The question is: How to write a code for each button so that the report displays (or save) the data in the sub-form according to the choice from each drop-down menu?

---

The code for each combo box:

```vb
Private Sub cmbCar_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cmbGroup.Value = ""
    Me.cmbType.Value = ""

    Me.frmCarSub.SetFocus
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.Filter = "[CarNum]= '" & [cmbCar] & "'"
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub cmbType_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cmbGroup.Value = ""
    Me.cmbCar.Value = ""

    Me.frmCarSub.SetFocus
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.Filter = "[TypeName]='" & [cmbType] & "'"
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub cmbGroup_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cmbCar.Value = ""
    Me.cmbType.Value = ""

    Me.frmCarSub.SetFocus
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.Filter = "[CarGroupName]= '" & [cmbGroup] & "'"
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

I used this code for btnPrint button

```vb
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
    If IsNull([cmbCar]) Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCar", acViewPreview
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCar", acViewPreview, , "[CarNum]='" & [cmbCar] & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```

But the problem with this code is that I have to use three buttons for the three menus and this is illogical.

Thank you.

Comment: Conditionally build filter criteria from the 3 comboboxes depending on if a choice is made. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. If a specific car from cmbCar is selected, there is no need for cmbType and cmbGroup parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function such as the following with the module for your form:

```
Function FilterString() As String
    If Not IsNull(cmbCar) Then FilterString = " AND [CarNum]= '" & cmbCar & "'"
    If Not IsNull(cmbType) Then FilterString = FilterString & " AND [TypeName]= '" & cmbType & "'"
    If Not IsNull(cmbGroup) Then FilterString = FilterString & " AND [CarGroupName]= '" & cmbGroup & "'"

    FilterString = Mid(FilterString, 6)
End Function
```

Then, define another function such as:

```
Function SetFilter()
    Me.frmCarSub.SetFocus
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.Filter = FilterString
    Me.frmCarSub.Form.FilterOn = True
End Function
```

Then, the event handlers for each of your comboboxes become:

```
Private Sub cmbCar_AfterUpdate()
    SetFilter
End Sub

Private Sub cmbType_AfterUpdate()
    SetFilter
End Sub

Private Sub cmbGroup_AfterUpdate()
    SetFilter
End Sub
```

Finally, the Print button event handler can become:

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
    If FilterString = vbNullString Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCar", acViewPreview
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCar", acViewPreview, , FilterString
    End If
End Sub
```

And the user also has the ability to filter by more than one field.